# Why my Xcode4.5 doesnt have a iphoneretinasimulator with 4 inch?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have downloaded xcode 4.5 from ios dev center.(dnt know is it the way).I got a dmg file.when i clicked on it to install it has only one xcode setup is there(nothing like samples,simulator folders which normally has).i inatalled it run my application .but when i got the simulator it has hardware options as ipad,ipad retina,iphone,iphone retina3.5,iphone retina 4 inch.only.the normal iphone simulator has the same screen reselution as 320,480.so the retina display has only the changed reselution screen.Is it correct.Can any body used this can guide me?

Comment: its hard to tell what you're asking but those are all the simulators there should be

Comment: @wattson12  i am asking is it the right kind of xcode 4.5.i doubted the authorisity.i have taken it from dev centeri am not getting the iphone simulator in 4 inch?only in retina it has 4 inch display?

Comment: the iPhone 5 (4 inch) doesn't have a non retina version. Getting Xcode from the dev center is OK, although it is easier for updates to use the app store version

Comment: ok ...that is wat i am asking.i do this because i want to keep the earlier ones also

Comment: at the moment you have a simulator for every iOS device resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that there is no low resolution Simulator, thats right. If you want a smaller Simulator, you can type CMD-3.

Comment: i am not getting u? i said i have only iphone 4 inch retina display only.not in ordinary simulator.is that in nature..

Comment: Sorry, it looks like i misunderstood you. No, you should have all the simulators of the past, plus the new 4-inch setting. Have tried to reset the simulator (iOS Simulator->Rest Content and Settings?

Comment: it has all the simulators.ipad,iphone ,iphone retina 3.5,retina 4.5 is that all have.but the 4 inch display only to retina simulators.not to the ordinary ones

Comment: yes, that is what I was trying to say in my answer above ;-)  The reason for that, is that there is no ordinary 4-inch display with a resolution of 568*480 - so there is no simulator for that. The 4-inch display is aonly existing as 1136*960 device (and simulator)